# Evolution du mot "aujourd'hui"

Tags: étymologie, histoire

**French version**: J'ai cherché l'étymologie du mot "aujourd'hui" et j'ai découvert qu'il vient de la construction

> **au** +‎ **jour** +‎ **de** +‎ **hui**

Cela veut dire “au jour d'hui”,  parce que *hui* vient du Latin **hoc** + **dies**. J'ai lu (mais je ne suis pas sûr de ça) qu'avant d'utiliser "aujourd'hui" les Français utilisaient "hui".

Mes questions sont :

1. Est-il vrai qu'ils utilisaient "hui" ?
2. Si c'est vrai, quelles en sont les raisons historiques ou sociales ?

---

**English version**: I've looked for the etymology of "aujourd'hui", and I found out that it comes from the construction:

> **au** +‎ **jour** +‎ **de** +‎ **hui**

It means “on the day of today”; since *hui* comes from Latin **hoc** + **dies**. I read (but I'm not sure about this) that before they used "auhourd'hui", French people used "hui".

My questions are:

1. Is it true?
2. If so, what are the historical or the social reasons?

Comment: J'utilise « hui » de temps à autres dans mes communications écrites.  Il n'est pas garanti que mon lecteur comprenne, mais c'est un mot que j'aime bien…
Certains aussi disent « au jour d'aujourd'hui, » ce qui contient trois fois la même information !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Oui, c'est tout à fait vrai. Au début du XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle, par exemple, *au jour d'ui* signifie « le jour où l'on est ». Puis *ui* est devenu *hui* et *aujourd'hui* est devenu un mot (après un passage par *aujourdui* à la fin du XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle).

Ceci est expliqué avec plus de détails [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aujourd%27hui) (voir section "ÉTYMOL. ET HIST." en fin de page).

Comment: Passe par http://www.cnrtl.fr, plutôt que par http://atilf.atilf.fr/, les liens sont plus stables.

Comment: Ah, merci ! Je ne connaissais pas cet accès. Il s'agit bien du même contenu?

Comment: Exact. Expliqué aussi ici: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdcf981oiYU :)

Comment: @LudoMC: Donc, l'explication est que "hui" était trés "faible"? J'avais lu cette chose, mais dans un forum, donc je n'était pas sûr. :)

Comment: @Shlublu: Merci pour l'indication, je n'avais pas vu cette section. :D

Comment: De rien @Alenanno !

Comment: @Shlublu Je vois que vous êtes très bon(ne) en étymologie. J'aime l'étymologie aussi.

Comment: Bah, c'est surtout le Trésor de la Langue Française qui est très bon :)
http://atilf.atilf.fr/

Answer (score 1):

This is expounded in R.L. Trask, Robert McColl Millar's [*Why Do Languages Change*? (2010 Rev. ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521546931). p. 24 Bottom

> In early Latin, ‘today’ was expressed by the phrase **hoc die*, literally ‘on this
>   day’, where the asterisk shows that this form is not recorded but has been

p. 25

> reconstructed by linguists. By the time of Classical Latin, this phrase had
>   coalesced into a single word, *hodie*, with the loss of one consonant in the
>   process.
>     By the time of the first Roman emperor, no Latin speaker was pronouncing
>   aitches any more. *Hodie* was now being pronounced *odie*, even though educated
>   people kept on writing the aitches because of the prestige of earlier writers.
>     In Paris, there were further changes in pronunciation, and in particular
>   more sounds were lost. In *hodie*, the sound /d/ disappeared, and after a while
>   speakers of the Parisian variety of Latin, which was beginning to be called
>   ‘French’, were writing their word for ‘today’ as *hui*, though that  was only
>   an act of obeisance to the ‘mother’ language, and what people were really
>   saying could have been written *ui*.
>     It appears that speakers of French were getting a little uncomfortable uttering
>   such a small noise to say ‘today’. So, they responded by creating a more
>   substantial way of expressing that concept. What they came up with was the
>   orotund phrase *au jour d’hui*, which is literally ‘on the day of today’. This
>   certainly solved the problem, and people began using this heavy expression
>   more and more often, until finally nobody was saying just plain *hui* any more at
>   all. Today the only possible way of saying ‘today’ in French is aujourd’hui,
>   which is now written as a single word, and the former *hui* is dead and buried.
>   Almost inevitably, this word can be reduced to something like *dwee* in colloquial speech.
>     Very likely you know somebody who is constitutionally incapable of uttering
>   the little English word now and who replaces it on every occasion with the
>   mouth-filling sequence at this moment in time. So far, this remains a pompous
>   piece of bureaucrat-speak, inveighed against by usage handbooks everywhere,
>   but there is no guarantee that it will not one day displace its shorter equivalent
>   altogether, much as has happened in French.

Comment: It seems to me that the  motivation for the use of "at this moment in time" is not so much to be sought in a concern which undertones have to do with  pomposity as a concern with a real need for precision, a must in administrative practices; one should not forget, for instance, that in English the time specified by "now" can be situated in the past; let's not forget, now (?), that the word might  even have nothing to do with time.