# Qu'est-ce que « hui » dans « aujourd'hui » ?

Tags: étymologie, indications-de-temps

Je me demande de temps en temps qu'est-ce que le mot « hui » dans aujourd'hui. Si on comprend « aujourd'hui » comme « au jour de » plus un mot, on pourrait penser que « hui » est justement un autre mot pour « maintenant » ou « ce moment ». Est-ce qu'il y a plus d'informations à ce sujet ?

Comment: Voir ici: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/727/evolution-du-mot-aujourdhui

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evolution du mot "aujourd'hui"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/727/evolution-du-mot-aujourdhui)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"*Aujourd'hui*" est un pléonasme : "*hui*" vient du latin "*[hŏdĭē](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DH%3Aentry%20group%3D16%3Aentry%3Dhodie)*", contraction de "*hoc die*", qui signifie "*en ce jour*". La forme complète signifie donc "*au jour de ce jour*".

Ce qui donne donc toute la dimension ridicule de la locution souvent entendue actuellement "*au jour d'aujourd'hui*", qui signifie littéralement "*au jour du jour de ce jour*".

Osez le double pléonasme :-)

Comment: Étonnamment on ne dis jamais "Au jour de mardi dernier". C'est vrai que cette expression bizarre. On devrait dire "à ce jour" ou bien "aujourd'hui" suffit réellement ?

Comment: @TCHdvlp je dirais qu'"aujourd'hui' indique la journée actuelle, alors qu'"à ce jour" indique plutôt le temps échu jusqu'au présent jour : "jusqu'à aujourd'hui".

Answer (score 3):

Il semble que hui signifie (signifiait) "ce jour". Et donc, aujourd'hui signifie "au jour de ce jour"...
Source : http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1470