# Why is there an apostrophe in the word « aujourd'hui » ?

Tags: mots-composés

As a beginner I found this word quite strange.  Why is there an apostrophe in the middle of the word « aujourd'hui » ? Is this word constructed by au + jour + d'hui ?

Comment: See also this answer : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12904/quest-ce-que-hui-dans-aujourdhui

Answer (score 4):

Oh well, I should have googled "etymology aujourd'hui" myself.  From Wiktionary I got this answer,

> au +‎ jour +‎ de +‎ hui, literally “on the day of today”; since hui
>   comes from Latin hodie, the phrase literally means "on the day of this
>   day".

Comment: This etymology makes even uglier the expression sometimes used "Au jour d'aujourd'hui".

Comment: I totally agree, this expression is ugly and is a kind of pleonasm !

Comment: @Hipjea even a double one, "aujourd'hui" already being an etymological pleonasm.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @grokus answer, we need to write that apostrophe because that is the rule with that ***[préposition](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/les-prepositions-29.php)*** when it stands before the ***h*** which is ***[muet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_muet)***.

You may be interested to read ***[Comment distingue-t-on  un "h" aspiré et  un "h" muet ?](http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire01ac.htm)***