# « Hui » et « aujourd'hui »

Tags: vocabulaire, ancien-français

Quelle est la différence entre « hui » et « aujourd'hui » ? Peut-on interchanger ces deux mots (sans tenir compte du fait que le premier est sans doute compris par moins de gens et moins naturel), et pourquoi dit-on « aujourd'hui » de nos jours alors que c'est beaucoup plus lourd que hui ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Evolution du mot "aujourd'hui"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/727/evolution-du-mot-aujourdhui)  https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12904/quest-ce-que-hui-dans-aujourdhui   https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16372/why-is-there-an-apostrophe-in-the-word-aujourdhui/16373?s=5|13.1700#16373

Comment: *Hui* n'est plus  utilisé depuis des siècles et ne serait en général pas compris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hui* n'est pas un mot du français moderne. Il était déjà archaïque en français classique : la première édition du *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*, en 1694 (c'est-à-dire pendant l'évolution du [français classique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_classique) vers le français moderne), [le définit ainsi](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k503971/f596.image) :

> HUY. adv. de temps servant à marquer le jour où l'on est. Ce mot est vieux, et n'est plus en usage qu'en terme de Pratique.

Par les réformes orthographiques du début du 18<sup>e</sup> siècle, l'orthographe est devenue *hui*. Le mot *Pratique* dans cette définition désigne la langue juridique. L' [édition actuelle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/hui) du *Dictionnaire* indique :

> Ne s'emploie plus que dans l'adverbe *Aujourd'hui* et dans la locution vieillie du langage juridique *Ce jour d'hui*. *Ce jour d'hui, les chambres assemblées.*

Le mot *hui* seul a complètement disparu de la langue courante en dehors de l'expression figée *aujourd'hui*. Même dans la langue juridique, *hui* n'est plus utilisé que dans quelques expressions figées.

Malgré l'apostrophe, linguistiquement, *aujourd'hui* constitue un seul mot. Le fait que son étymologie soit la fusion de quatre mots (*au*, *jour*, *d'*, *hui*), et que dans ancêtre du français *hui* avait le même sens, ne change rien à cela. Par exemple, on l'abrège [*auj.*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/auj.) et non *<strike>a.j.d.h.</strike>.

Un français cultivé comprendra certainement *hui*, mais risque d'hésiter à l'oral si le contexte n'est pas clair. Mais il sera remarqué comme archaïque.

Answer (score -1):

Le mot couramment utilisé est "aujourd'hui".

Quant à ton interrogation "mais pourquoi alors que c'est plus long ?", et bien on ne sait pas. Une habitude je pense.