# « Au jour d'aujourd'hui » : sens particulier de la locution avec l'adverbe, emploi fautif ?

Tags: sens, adverbes, locutions

Ces derniers temps, dans la presse (belge), je lis souvent la locution « **au jour d'aujourd'hui** ». En appui à ce dont je me souviens de mon latin, [je lis](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/12907/3177) que « hui » vient de « hoc die » (hŏdĭē) qui signifie déjà « en ce jour ». Cela fait donc d' « aujourd'hui » un pléonasme...

---

- « Au jour d'aujourd'hui » a-t-il un sens (ou autre chose) qui diffère d'*aujourd'hui* ?

  - est-ce un emploi fautif ?
  - est-il d'un usage récent ?
  - est-ce davantage un pléonasme qu'avec *aujourd'hui* ?
- Que signifierait « au jour du jour d'aujourd'hui » ?

Comment: C'est une figure d'insistance, qui est effectivement un pléonasme, mais est utilisé pour insister sur le fait que l'on parle bien de ce jour précis, pas d'hier ni de demain.

Comment: [L'académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/au-jour-daujourdhui) catégorise cette expression comme un _emploi fautif_. Le [wikitionaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_jour_d%E2%80%99aujourd%E2%80%99hui) parle de "locution doublement redondante".

Comment: Expression pas spécialement belge et depuis longtemps dans la langue française. *À trancher une bonne fois pour toutes : « au jour d’aujourd’hui »* [sur le Projet Voltaire](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/pleonasme-au-jour-daujourdhui). Après je dirais que c'est une question de goût personnel.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ce n'est pas un doublon : ici, je demande explicitement si c'est une faute, ce qui n'est pas décrit dans l'autre réponse.

Comment: @SurvenantLazurite Je suis un béotien sur ce site. Ce que vous me demandez me semble un chouia trop compliqué pour un intérêt minime. Peut-être pourriez-vous expliciter la démarche que vous recherchez plutôt que de m'inviter à suivre une liste d'actions incompréhensibles. Vous pouvez toujours améliorer vous-même la question si vous le pensez nécessaire : je suis un fervent partisan de la collaboration.

Comment: Malgré la forme malheureuse, il me semble bien qu'"aujourd'hui" signifie "ce jour", contrairement à "ajd'ajd" qu'on utilise pour dire "**à** ce jour" (avec une perspective sur le passé). Donc… oui la forme est risiblement pléonastique, mais non, ça ne veut pas dire la même chose, et clairement, c'est employé différemment. Je pense aussi que ça mérite d'être ré-ouvert.

Answer (score 5):

« Au jour d'aujourd'hui », peut remplacer le « hic et nunc » des latinistes, « l'ici et maintenant » des philosophes.

Le *'Pléonasme tautologique redondant'* est un style 'café du commerce' ou 'débat télévisuel' où chacun s'exprime en toute liberté avec les moyens dont il dispose.

Comme il fait grincer les dents académiques, il est à manier avec ironie à l'écrit, et avec connivence dans les dialogues, sinon il signe une faiblesse dans la connaissance du français, il faut alors le considérer comme une faute.

P.S. : Si l'expression ne comporte que des références au temps, à *maintenant*, vous remarquerez que très souvent le locuteur pointe le sol à ses pieds à l'aide d'un ou deux de ses index  pour manifester l'*ici* pendant qu'il prononce sa phrase... tout en voulant insister sur l'instant présent.

Comment: Pertinent : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/727/evolution-du-mot-aujourdhui

Comment: Encore un vote négatif sans commentaire... et encore un rappel de la charte de ce site qui demande de les justifier pour permettre l'amélioration des réponses.

Comment: Un lien vers cette charte ? S'il est vraiment demandé de justifier ses votes, c'est une incitation à moins voter.

Comment: http://french.stackexchange.com/help/behavior : **Be honest**.

Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better answers of your own. Last but not least, edit and improve the existing questions and answers! By doing these things, you are helping keep Stack Exchange a great place to share knowledge of our craft.

Comment: Et ben ? Ça dit "participez !", pas "quand vous votez négativement, vous devez ajouter un commentaire". Sinon, il faudrait lire "quitte à participer, votez, mettez des commentaires, répondez vous-mêmes, et n'oubliez surtout pas de modifier les réponses existantes !", par la même logique.

Comment: Rien ne vous empêche de proposer vos solutions sur meta... Ce n'est pas une question de vote, mais de qualité du site, qui ne s'intéresse pas aux opinions, mais aux idées.

Answer (score 2):

Le [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/aujourdhui/6459/locution?q=aujourd%20hui#159897) et le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aujourd'hui) classent la locution comme familière, le second parlant d'une « expression pléonastique, employée souvent ironiquement » (« *Je ne crois donc pas à la fin du monde après la destruction de ce qui est au jour d'aujourd'hui.* » de Goncourt en 1873) mais renvoyant à une remarque au [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/aujourd%27hui) qui qualifiait le tour de *peu recommandable* tout en saluant le vers de Lamartine « L'univers est à lui [Dieu], Et nous n'avons à nous Que le jour d'aujourd'hui » et le TLFi d'ajouter entre parenthèses « le jour d'aujourd'hui = le jour qu'est aujourd'hui c.-à-d. la date, le moment que constitue le jour où nous sommes ».

Larousse définit quant à lui : « Au jour d'aujourd'hui, par les temps qui courent, actuellement » et parle d'un [*double pléonasme*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/aujourd_hui/6459/difficulte), de l'opposition entre le moment présent et le passé.

*Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, 14<sup>e</sup>) note qu'*au jour d'aujourd'hui* exprime trois fois l'idée de jour et qu'on le trouve parfois dans la langue littéraire ; par exemple, Beauvoir, « Vous trouvez qu'au jour d'aujourd'hui, c'est vain ? ». Le [contexte](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ss_xAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22Vous%20trouvez%20qu%27au%20jour%20d%27aujourd%27hui%2C%20c%27est%20vain%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22au%20jour%20d%27aujourd%27hui%2C%20c%27est%20vain%22) fait penser que ce serait l'emploi décrit au Larousse (de nos jours, par les temps qui courent ; *aujourd'hui* peut lui aussi avoir ce sens). On suggère de comparer avec l'emploi chez Lamartine. On s'autorise aussi diverses variations sur le thème d'*aujourd'hui*, par exemple Gide, « Peiné sur Corydon tout le jour d'hier et d'hui » etc. (LBU14, §1005 c, note H2). En regardant les plus anciens résultats d'un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=au%20jour%20d%27aujourd%27hui&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cau%20jour%20d%27%20aujourd%27hui%3B%2Cc0) on voit ça dans l’œuvre d'Amantine Aurore Lucile Dupin par exemple. Quant à l'*Académie française*, son site web classe la locution dans la catégorie des [*emplois fautifs*](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/au-jour-daujourdhui), mais ce ne saurait être déterminant considérant l'introduction qu'on lui réserve, la timidité du verbe *préférer* et le fait qu'on restreigne la suggestion au cas où l'on veut parler d'une *journée* qu'on évoque :

> Cette formule jouant sur la redondance a une résonance familière et
>   plaisante. Pour parler de la journée présente ou de celle que l’on
>   évoque, on préfèrera dire *Aujourd’hui* ou *Ce jour*. On peut aussi
>   recourir à la tournure ancienne *Ce jour d’hui*.

---

Ce n'est ni fautif, ni récent, c'est plus pléonastique, et ça peut être employé de manière ironique. Quant à « [au jour du jour d'aujourd'hui](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_jour_du_jour_d%E2%80%99aujourd%E2%80%99hui) », c'est très rare et relève de la blague (Wiktionnaire) où l'on s'amuse aux dépens de ce fameux [jour d'hui](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/22189)...