# Pourquoi "jusqu'à aujourd'hui" au lieu de "jusqu'aujourd'hui" ?

Tags: usage, locutions, registre

> Jusqu'à aujourd'hui est maintenant couramment admis, à côté de jusqu'aujourd'hui qui est d'un emploi littéraire et recherché.

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/aujourd_hui/6459

*Aujourd'hui* signifie *à le jour d'hui*. Puisque la préposition à y est déjà pourquoi dit-on couramment jusqu'à aujourd'hui ? N'est-ce pas moins correct ?

Comment: Ne soit pas si rapide à accepter une réponse qui n'est pas une réponse basée sur un savoir scientifique prouvé.  Si j'avais dit une bêtise, tu ne peux pas le savoir puisque tu as posé la question.  Tu peux peut-être attendre que quelqu'un confirme ou infirme. Si je dis une bêtise je suis sure que quelqu'un (auquel on puisse faire confiance) le dira. Attendre 24 heures n'est pas de trop pour accepter ce genre de réponse, sauf si plusieurs personnes plussoient, auquel cas je suppose qu'on peut faire confiance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mis à part les étymologistes et les [curieux qui s'intéressent à la langue](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/727/358), l'étymologie du mot est complètement oubliée par la très grande majorité des francophones. *Aujourd'hui* est perçu comme une unité lexicale (même si parfois la présence de l'apostrophe, interpelle et peut créer des difficultés dans l'apprentissage de l'orthographe) et la syllabe *au* a perdu son sens de *à le* et la redondance n'est pas perçue. Et c'est tout à fait correct de dire *jusqu'à aujourd'hui*.

*Dictionnaire des pièges et difficultés de la langue française* (Jean Girodet, 2010) :

> ***Jusqu'aujourd'hui***. Forme préconisé par les grammairiens, à la place de *jusqu'à aujourd'hui*, pour éviter les pléonasme, car la préposition *à* est déjà contenue dans aujourd'hui (= *à le jour d'hui*). Cependant *jusqu'à aujourd'hui* est toléré dans l'usage général et *jusqu'aujourd'ui* est légèrement archaique et précieux.

L'usage de *jusqu'aujourd'hui* est probablement resté majoritaire tant que les élites, les seules qui connaissaient la langue écrite, apprenaient le latin et conservaient la mémoire de l'étymologie du mot.
Si l'usage de *jusqu'aujourd'hui* est considéré de nos jours comme littéraire, c'est qu'il a été progressivement remplacé par *jusqu'à aujourd'hui* (la courbe s'inverse à la fin des années 1950), alors que l'enseignement secondaire commençait à se massifier, et qu'en même temps le pourcentage des personnes apprenant le latin dans l’enseignement secondaire diminuait.

[image]