# Le mot aujourd'hui, "le bon usage"

Tags: vocabulaire

Dans l'histoire de la langue française, j'ai lu que les puristes du XVII<sup>e</sup> s. détestaient le mot *aujourd'hui* (et *aucunefois, au surplus, généralement, quasi*).

Je me demande quel mot ils employaient à la place ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evolution du mot "aujourd'hui"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/727/evolution-du-mot-aujourdhui)

Comment: Je doute qu'ils employaient "hui" au XVII s.

Comment: Et pourtant : https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/aujourd'hui

Comment: *Hui* était déjà obsolète au 17e siècle, mais certains puristes le regrettaient. En 1684, l'[Académie française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A1H0167) notait que « ce mot est vieux ». L'ultraconservateur [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/hui) regrettait cela encore au 19e siècle. De quoi doutes-tu ?

Comment: Peut-être il y avait un autre mot qu'ils préféraient

Comment: Ngram : [Aujourd'hui vs Ce jour](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ce+jour%2CAujourd%27hui&year_start=1650&year_end=1850&case_insensitive=on&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)